# Resampling a digital sound signal

Tags: resampling, digital-filters

As a non maths-pro, I'm looking for some pointers.

I am rewriting the audio core in my emulator to improve accuracy, and am getting a bit stuck on the specifics of the technique.

I am trying to resample a sample buffer of 4,466 samples, at a sample rate of 223,807.5 Hz (from a simulated Yamaha SN76489), to a sample buffer of 880 samples at a sample rate of 44,100 Hz, which can then be output to a sound card.

Now from what I understand, as the ratio between 44,100 and 223,807.5 Hz is 5.075, I need to turn this into a fraction, which works out as 203/40, and then interpolate by the denominator (leaving 0 samples inbetween), run a low-pass filter, and then decimate by the numerator, giving me my 880 samples of 44,100 Hz output.

(1) Am I along the right lines here? Before I was just downsampling by a straight 5 (i.e. missing out 4 of every 5 samples) and whilst it worked well enough, some notes are slightly out of key in some games, and there is aliasing. Is this new approach correct?

(2) Also, I am not sure what would do the trick in terms of a low-pass filter. I found the following pseudocode on wikipedia that seems to fit the bill:

```
    // Return RC low-pass filter output samples, given input samples,
    // time interval dt, and time constant RC
    function lowpass(real[0..n] x, real dt, real RC)
       var real[0..n] y
       var real α := dt / (RC + dt)
       y[0] := x[0]
       for i from 1 to n
           y[i] := α * x[i] + (1-α) * y[i-1]
       return y
```

But I have no idea how to get RC and dt - what are these in relation to the filter I wish to achieve? As I don't know how to select suitable values here, the output signal is heavily garbled at the moment. If a better/more understandable formula is available then by all means suggest it. Sorry for the newbish question and I hope this is the right place for it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Absolutely fine by me - thank you for your time :-)

Comment: what about efficiency ? As for the emulator, do you seek to be more accurate or more efficient ?

Comment: At the moment I'd like something I can actually understand - efficiency is good but understanding is the key for me.

Comment: your approach is correct. It will produce what you want. But if you directly implement it, due to high interpolation of the initial stage, the required lowpass filter must be capable of removing all the images (due to upsampling - filling with zeros) before decimation to avoid aliasing. Most probably it is the low-pass filter who creates the problem.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. The low-pass filter is where I get caught up sadly. I just need something simple that can attenuate anything above a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz - and I somehow need to understand it too.

Comment: Oops I may have just deleted your comment - bloody hands on this tiny phone screen - sorry. I'm emulating an SN76489 as part of the Master System/Game Gear. In these systems it runs at 1/16th of the CPU clock speed, and generates one sample per clock, so for NTSC as an example, it is 3,579,545 / 16, giving a sampling rate of around 223 KHz - I made the ratio 5.075 to make the math easier but it is a really long decimal roughly equivalent to this. You are correct that only the 20 Hz to 20 KHz range is important to me,  which is why I've chosen the sampling rate of 44.1 KHz.

Comment: Actually I've deleted it. I made a simple matlab simulation and it shows that filter is not adequate. You need to select a very low alpha parameter. Yes this simple filter is quite efficient as it would require just one multiplication per output but those recursive filters have many drawbacks outside their good use, such as nonlinear phase. I can offer you many things. First you can use very efficient polyphase implementations. But my suggestion is simplest linear-interpolation which is both efficient and accurate enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this approach provided it does not yield efficiency burdens.

```
% Note that matlab arrays start from index 1, not 0.
F1 = 223807.5;     % Sampling rate of Yamaha chip
F2 = 44100;        % New sampling rate of standard Audio-CD
M = 203;           % Necessary Decimation ratio
N = 40;            % necessary Expansion ratio
Lx = 4466;         % Length of Audio Input Buffer at F1 rate
Ly = Lx*N/M;       % Length of Resampled Output Buffer at F2 rate


x = sin(2*pi*1234*[0:Lx-1]/F1);  % Just a test sine wave
y = zeros(1,Ly);                 % allocate output signal memory

for i=0:Ly-1              % run per each output sample
   n = i*(M/N);          % compute exact sampling position inside the long buffer 
   ind = floor(n);       % convert it into largest integer smaller than itself for array indexing
   d = n-ind;            % take the difference for proportional weighting
   y(i+1) = (1-d)*x(ind+1) + d*x(ind+2); % sum the weighted mixture.
end

figure,plot(x);            %plot each waveforms...
figure,plot(y);
```

Comment: So would I be right in thinking this is similar to the approach I found on Wikipedia, except it interpolates the points in the output buffer directly?

Comment: No they are different approaches. The one you want to proceed uses a theoretically exact approach by performing [upsampling-->filtering-->downsampling] operations. This approach produces exact sample values but requires more computation. The one I suggest uses much less computation and provides quite accurate but not exact values proportional to oversampling of original signal.

Comment: Sorry, probably seems like a stupid question :-) Thank you for your help, this approach seems to make sense in my head and looks relatively simple to convert to C - I shall try it tonight and it will hopefully give me better results :-)

Comment: Would I be correct in deducing that "y(i+1) = (1-d)*x(ind+1) + d*x(ind+2)" is responsible for smoothing the output signal also, due to the difference value used?

Comment: Yes! Just try it to observe computational performance and resulting accuracy. If both are acceptable it's juts fine. Else if accuracy is not acceptable but performance still allows we can always improve the interpolator..

Comment: I'll let you know how I get on :-D

Comment: There are different approaches to interpret the effect of the interpolation kernel. The simplest one is to see it as a method of computing an intermediate value between two samples of original signal, assuming they are interconnected by a line.

Comment: The approach works as mentioned. I do get quite a bit of high-pitched crackling though. I thought this might be due to the sample buffer being too small so I increased it by a factor of 5, but same problem. Any idea how I can combat this?

Comment: when converting to C, do yo take care of the array indices? in matlab they start from 1, in C from 0. In java ? if it starts from 0, then decrease array indices by 1 on the last line. Also ckeck for the last sample of the buffer.

Comment: Yes I've accounted for the array indices already. What do you mean by check for the last sample?

Comment: just a practical hint. generally last sample may disrupt the continuity of the buffer and result in glitches pops or cracks. By the way I've tested it and noticed no such distortion on the audio output... You must provide more information. For example when you increased the buffer size by 5, did the pitch of the crack change ?

Comment: The pitch does of the crack does not change, and it is relatively minor. I could provide source code if you are happy to read it - I don't want to clog up this comment thread anymore than I already have though :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34146/discussion-between-fat32-and-philpotter1987).

Answer (score 1):

For a ratio of such large integers, you might be better off directly interpolating values at the sample points for the new sample rate using a high quality interpolator, rather than upsampling followed by downsampling.  A windowed Sinc interpolation kernel of suitable width can include it's own anti-alas low-pass filter.